# What should the file permissions be for files in the Pictures folder on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, pictures

I have a mac book pro running Yosemite.
The Photos application shows images but when I double click them I get a dialog that says Photos is not able to locate the file and asks me to select the location of the image file.
 When I go to the folder where the file is and try to select it the files are all greyed out.
 **I reckon it is a file permissions issue, so what should be the file permissions for files in the Pictures folder on mac?**

Comment: I don't know much about OS-X, but I do understand the Linux which underpins it. You need read permission to display a file, with execute permission on all directories in its path and read permission on any directories you need to browse. If you start a terminal and `cd` to the directory containing your images and then type `ls -l`, you will see the file permissions, with their owner and group names, which will tell you if you need to read as owner, group or other; `file *` will verify that you can read the files if the file type is shown. But OS-X could superimpose additional security levels.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a permission issue, I'd set 755 and 644 for folders and files respectively. So under Pictures folder you can do:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

and for files do,

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

**PS: Backup everything first !**